# Starting up a node

Tags: node

I just started looking at Shimmer network and I wanted to setup a node.  I'm on Ubuntu.  I've followed the setup guide but when I run the command "wasp -c wasp-node', 'wasp' command not found.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. You've successfully built the binaries.
2. The location of your binaries.

You can follow the guide here to install properly: [Installing Wasp on Wiki.](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/smart-contracts/guide/chains_and_nodes/installing-wasp)

If you're setting up using `make build` then the binaries ideally stay in the root directory. In which case, you'd need to run: `./wasp` instead of `wasp`.
If you've run `make install`, then the binaries should be on the global path and be accessible using `wasp`. If you do not have go path setup, follow [this](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/smart-contracts/guide/chains_and_nodes/installing-wasp#add-binaries-to-path).

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I followed the instructions here, https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/smart-contracts/guide/chains_and_nodes/installing-wasp.  Though my PATH for Go is '/usr/local/go/bin/go', I can still run the 'go' command from anywhere.  I used the 'make install' command.  When I run 'wasp', I get 'no such file or directory'.  If I run './wasp', I get a 'Command 'wasp' not found, did you mean:...' but no command example for 'wasp'.